# A guest login, is my system vulnerable?

Tags: login, users, log, guest-session

I logged out of my Ubuntu laptop and came back to a guest session open asking whether to continue with the guest session logout which will cause the temporary information to lose. Apparently somebody might have logged in while I was gone.

The following is a screenshot from the auth file but I don't know how to analyze it.

[image: Log screenshot]

I was out from 3.39pm to 4.35pm.

At 3.50pm a new group and a user was created by the looks of it. Is my system vulnerable to anything?

Comment: Please don’t post screenshots of text. Paste the text into the question instead.

Comment: I'd say your system has been well and truly compromised. The creation of new groups and users is not something you want to happen when you turn your back. Also, an attempt was made to fiddle with your KWallet. Luckily for you, they didn't have time to remove their traces. Backup your data and reinstall.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the privileges of a guest are [highly restricted](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html).

Comment: @Jos So somebody tried and failed? Or how to find if they were successful in it? However, I had some hangout messages when I logged in, so can the attempts be by the system? (Sorry if it is a really dumb question)

Comment: @Jos The log entries related to `pam_kwallet.so` are from after 4:35 PM. Plus, that always happens whenever you log out (I just confirmed this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, there is no evidence that the attacker gained access to your system.

Let's go through the relevant log entries:

```
new group: name=guest-slrfad, GID=999
new user: name=guest-slrfad, UID=999, GID=999, home=/tmp/guest-slrfad, shell=/bin/bash
Successful su for guest-slrfad by root
+ ???  root:guest-slrfad
session opened for user guest-slrfad by (uid=0)
New session c3 of user guest-slrfad.
[more "session opened/closed" messages]
```

The attacker is **not** creating this account; the system is. The attacker is only logging into a guest session, and you can't do anything to the system in a guest session (you don't even have a home directory on the hard drive; you only have a temporary one in RAM which is removed when you log out of it).

```
session opened for user root by (uid=1001)
Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/sachithra] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
```

Again, this is normal and is being done by the system, not by the attacker.

```
CRON[13099]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
CRON[13099]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
CRON[13203]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
CRON[13203]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

This is also normal; the system is just doing routine tasks. This has nothing to do with the guest session.

---

And everything else is after 4:35 PM. So no, there is no evidence that the attacker did anything to your system.

Comment: At 4.09pm, sesssions were created for root, was this too done by the system?

Comment: @SachDan As I said at the end of my answer, yes.  `cron` opening sessions for root is normal and is done by the system.